# What is the point of the diode in parallel to the fan here?

Tags: diodes, npn

Sorry - no background in EE so this might be a bit of stupid question.

I'm looking at this [simple circuit](https://www.electroschematics.com/arduino-fan-speed-controlled-temperature/) and am trying to understand the point of the 14N007 diode that is put in parallel to the fan in an NPN transistor switch circuit.

I thought diodes were only used if an inductive load were to be expected and thus its used to dissipate any EMF generated.

[image]

Comment: Hee, hee. Connect a battery to the fan and with the fan running, put ONE hand across the fan's terminals then disconnect the battery. Did you feel a shock and jump high? Then try it with a diode parallel to the fan and feel no shock.

Comment: The diode shorts out the fan while it is generating a back EMF pulse as the coils are collapsing. Yes it is an inductor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct regarding the diode to clamp the back EMF of an inductive load. The fan has a motor that has inductance but also a motor controller that most likely has the required protection already, so the extra diode is a precaution.

Comment: Thanks. I was being silly and should have realised that the fan = motor= induction.  Would I be correct in saying a capacitor could also be used to dampen the voltage spike? Is there a drawback to using a capacitor instead?

Comment: A capacitor may (or may not) be bigger, more expensive, and potentially not limit the voltage as effectively as a diode. It can cause inrush current, and because of its low impedance at high frequencies it might make it more difficult to control the fan speed with PWM. YMMV. A diode is simpler, there are fewer variables and you don't need as much math to predict how it will behave.

Answer (score 3):

This diode in [antiparallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_(electronics)) with the fan is indeed a [freewheeling diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) to protect the NPN transistor against [back EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) from the fan motor.